# Your app(s) are using a WebView that is vulnerable to cross-app scripting Android PlayStore Warning

Tags: android, webview, android-security

In whistleIt we load static url in webview and handle notification and other things but in last 2 versions we receive warning

> Your app(s) are using a WebView that is vulnerable to cross-app scripting

We are not using `android:exported=”true“` in our activity also i am using below code in Webview activity but still getting warning email.

```
<meta-data android:name="android.webkit.WebView.EnableSafeBrowsing"
android:value="true" />
```

what should i do now so our warning will get removed?

Comment: Hi, eventually how did you solve it? thx.

Answer (score 1):

Please add this line of code in your project manifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="android.webkit.WebView.EnableSafeBrowsing"
 android:value="true" />
```

Comment: `webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(false);` add this line

Comment: I am also capture image within webview and for that using native cam so after add this line is my flow work?

Comment: Are you sure with this line warning solve?

Comment: yeah 80% sure you can check it

Answer (score 1):

according to https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9084685?hl=en-GB

you can do 2 things

1 Ensure that affected activities are not exported

> Find any Activities with affected WebViews. If these Activities do not
> need to take Intents from other apps you can set
> android:exported=false for the Activities in your Manifest. This
> ensures that malicious apps cannot send harmful inputs to any WebViews
> in these activities.

2 Protect WebViews in exported activities

> If you want to set an Activity with an affected WebView as exported
> then we recommend that you make the following changes:
>
> 1 Protect calls to evaluateJavascript and loadUrl

> Ensure that parameters
> to evaluateJavascript are always trusted. Calling evaluateJavascript
> using unsanitised input from untrusted intents lets attackers execute
> harmful scripts in the affected WebView. Similarly, calling loadUrl
> with unsanitised input containing javascript: scheme URLs lets
> attackers execute harmful scripts.
>
> 2 Prevent unsafe file loads

> Ensure that affected WebViews cannot load
> the cookie database. WebViews that load unsanitised file:// URLs from
> untrusted intents can be attacked by malicious apps in two steps.
> First step: a malicious web page can write  tags into the
> cookies database. Second step: this modified cookies database file can
> be loaded if a malicious app sends an intent with a file:// URL
> pointing to your WebView cookies database, or if the malicious web
> page itself redirects your WebView to the file URL. The malicious
>
> stored in the cookies database will load and execute, which
> can steal session information.

You can ensure that affected WebViews cannot load the WebView cookies
database in three ways.

1. Disable all file access.
2. Make sure that the WebView only loads
   file:// URLs and verify that any loaded file:// URLs point to safe
   files. Note that an attacker can use a symbolic link to trick checks
   on the URL path. To prevent such an attack, make sure that you check
   the canonical path of any untrusted file:// URL before loading
   instead of just checking the URL path.
3. If you want to allow both
   http:// URLs and file:// URLs, implement the file:// URL
   verification using shouldOverrideUrlLoading and
   shouldInterceptRequest in WebViewClient. This ensures that all URLs
   loaded into WebView are verified, not limited to the URLs directly
   provided to a loadUrl() function call.